# What does "hold someone by the arm" mean?

Tags: prepositions, sentence-meaning

To me, the sentence [*He held his daughter by the arm*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/the) implies holding a baby in the arm like this photo:
[image]

However is there any ambiguity here in the meaning? Can this mean *he kept his daughter from going by pressing and keeping her arm*?!

Comment: Remember that in English, a reference to a body-part of the subject of an active sentence usually has a possessive, eg _I hurt **my** leg_, _She nodded **her** head_, _Close **your** mouth_. Use of _the_ before a body part nearly always means it belongs to somebody else mentioned or implied in the sentence.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The photo in your question shows a man holding a baby *in* his arm, or cradling a baby in his arm.

We usually mean something like this when we say *hold **by** the arm.*

[image]

It often describes a method to keep someone from leaving, yes.

Comment: In my browser (Google Chrome), after I followed your link I just right-clicked on the picture and selected "Copy image". That stored a copy of the picture on my PC, which I could then "drag" from my "downloads" folder into the "Add image" dialog box invoked from the leftmost of the "Edit Answer" icons. It's *much* more complicated to include Google NGram charts though.

Comment: It isn't necessarily to restrain them, it might be to assist them.  "I was frightened because there were no side-rails, so  Joan held me by the arm as we went up the stairs."

Answer (score 4):

I would describe the picture in your question in this way:

> He held is daughter ***in*** his arm.

[image]
However, in the picture above, we might say:

A: The father is holding his son **by the arm**.
B: The brother and sister are **holding hands**.
C: The daughter is **holding her mother's hand**.

Comment: Since we have a picture, there's no danger of anything being misunderstood. But if I were describing the scene to a blind person I'd say *The father is **holding his son's arm*** (using the same construction as your example C). To me, your version A strongly implies a father "restraining" his son, but there's nothing in the picture to suggest that the boy is being "held back" in any way.

Comment: @Fumble - I probably would, too, but I think _hold_ is a flexible enough verb that it could be said either way. In this case, I deliberately wanted to use a different construct than the one used in (C).

Answer (score 3):

There's no real ambiguity. When we speak of *“holding someone by the arm”* we almost always mean ***restraining*** them, by firmly grasping **their** arm.

So a native speaker might say the man in OP's picture is ***cradling*** his daughter [in/with/using one arm]. We wouldn't say he's holding her ***by*** the arm, because that would probably be misinterpreted.

Comment: Can we instead of *one arm* use *the arm*? I mean *the man is cradling his daughter in/with/using the arm.*

Comment: @Juya: Idiomatically, no. Usually you'd cradle a baby in *both* arms, so it's meaningful to actually specify ***one** arm* if you think it's important to flag up the casual [unsafe?] alternative. If that's unimportant we might say ***his** arm*, but ***the** arm* is unlikely (presumably because as pointed out in the answer, people would be likely to interpret ***the** arm* as referring to the baby's arm).